# Getting off a Flixbus

Tags: europe, flixbus

I've never traveled with a Flixbus before and I'm wondering when I need to know to get off my bus. Do I just need to look in the app constantly? Or can I wait until the bus driver says we're at this stop?

Comment: You could ask the driver when you board - "Do I need to signal when I want to get off, or will you announce all stops?"

Comment: When in doubt, use the GPS on your phone to check your real-time position.

Comment: Don't be shy to tell the driver during the ticket check that you're new to the system. Then ask them if they could possibly announce <name of your stop>. They will most certainly tell you that they will announce it anyway, but simultaneously they will become aware of a first-time passenger. Communicate.

Comment: Just be aware of the current time and the time you should arrive, and you wont miss your stop. I once was on a bus someone did miss their stop, and they pestered the bus driver to let them off somewhere on the highway - naturally he didn't, but please keep this in mind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my experience with Flixbus (in Germany), the driver announced each upcoming stop around five minutes before it was reached. With passengers embarking / disembarking and loading / unloading luggage, the bus usually stayed at a stop for at least 5-10 minutes.

So you don't need to be looking at the app constantly, but it is still a good idea to be generally aware of when the bus will reach your stop and be alert around then. In particular, it would be helpful to at least keep in mind when the next stop is yours.

I believe that the bus always stops at every stop (i.e., does not skip stops if no one signals that they intend to embark / disembark), and this was always the case in my trips, but I am not sure if this is generally true. Flixbus allows tickets to be purchased on the spot in the bus, so I think it is highly likely that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I'm scared to miss the stop so hearing this helps

Comment: Good answer. I just want to add that you cannot predict in which language stop names will be announced. On a bus going through Spain, France and Germany, I once had all announcements in Italian... Sometimes, it's better and they do it in all the languages they know.

Comment: @camel Similarly, the buses Berlin-Oslo and Berlin-Stockholm are run by Czech contractor Umbrella, whose drivers often barely speak enough German/English to make a clear announcement (and butcher the names of Swedish localities to the point of unintelligibility). Being from Sweden but living in Switzerland I frequently "commute" on that route.

Comment: Having an offline map in your phone helps. In Europe, I have a good experience with https://mapy.cz/?mobilepromo=1. @Crazydre That actually makes Flixbus an attractive option to me, since I am Czech myself.

Comment: @Someonexxx you should be able to find out in the app the approximate time of arrival? So, obviously, if it's still 2 hours to go, you are unlikely at your destination right now. Also, using GPS on the phone helps for the piece of mind (if you're conscious of the Internet, you can obviously download the map even in Google Maps before travelling so that you're only using GPS - in case you have no Internet in the country where you are travelling).

Comment: (+1) Same experience on various international lines (with the same caveat than Crazydre) but stops are always marked and announced in advance. Importantly, during the night, the driver will turn on the lights a few minutes before stopping.

Comment: Same here. Once or twice I got off at a stop that was listed as "demand stop" (Bedarfshaltestelle) on the timetable, meaning the bus would only stop there if pax wanted to get off or had a ticket booked from that stop at least an hour beforehand. With the ticket booked well in advance, there was no need to tell the driver anything or signal to get off. He already knew someone wanted to get off, procedures were the same as with any other stop.